# Como obtener datos de de un solo campo de una tabla sql con c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
cmd.CommandText = "select permisos.nombre_permiso from detalle_permisos inner join permisos" +
        "on detalle_permisos.id_permiso = permisos.id_permiso inner join" +
        "tipos_usuarios on detalle_permisos.id_tipo_usuario = tipos_usuarios.id_tipo_usuario where tipos_usuarios.nombre = @tipo_us";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("tipo_us", tipo_user);

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Usuarios us = new Usuarios();
            us.Permisos = reader.GetString(0);
            Debug.WriteLine(us.Permisos);
            permisos.Add(us.Permisos);
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
        return permisos;
```

El metodo retorna una lista tipo string gracias por la ayuda de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) @edwin_fuentes. Está bien que recurras a la comunidad para preguntar y recibir propuestas que ayuden a responder tu inquietud, pero para que la respuesta pueda ser de buena calidad y logre responder tu inquietud necesitamos que nos expliques mejor tu problema e incluir algún ejemplo de lo que necesitas, explica detalladamente tu inquietud. Te recomiendo leer este artículo: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Podria ser algo como esto

```
string query = @"select p.nombre_permiso 
                from detalle_permisos d
                inner join permisos p on d.id_permiso = p.id_permiso 
                inner join tipos_usuarios t on d.id_tipo_usuario = t.id_tipo_usuario 
                where t.nombre = @tipo_us";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_us", tipo_user);

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    Usuarios us = new Usuarios();
    us.Permisos = reader["nombre_permiso"].ToString();

    permisos.Add(us.Permisos);
}
```

Algunos comentarios

- Para hacer un string multilinea usa el `@`
- Para recuperar solo un registro de la query no uses el `while` solo usa el `if`
- puedes acceder al dato del campo por su nombre en el `reader`

Comment: Esta resuelto muchas gracias !!!!!